# How do I sort a list of items where each item may refer to items that should come before or after it

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have a list/`IEnumerable<T>` of items that need to be sorted.

Under most conditions I would have implemented `IComparable<T>` on the items and that'd be it.
However, there is a small problem this time, namely that each item also has a list of other items that should come after it, and a list of items that should come before it.

A representation of what it looks like:

```cs
public class Item
{
    // The item's own ID
    public string Id
    {
        get;
    }

    // A list of IDs of items that should come before this one
    // i.e. this item comes AFTER all these items
    public IEnumerable<string> After
    {
        get;
    }

    // A list of IDs of items that should come after this one
    // i.e. this item comes BEFORE all these items
    public IEnumerable<string> Before
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

So given an example set of items

```
1 (after 2)
2 (after 3, before 1)
3 (before 5, 4, 2, 1)
4 (after 5)
5
```

one of the valid sorted outputs would be `3, 2, 5, 4, 1`.

There may be other valid orders as well, since some elements may not specify whether they should come after or before another (for example, `3, 5, 2, 4, 1` in this case would also be a valid sorting since `2` and `5` don't care about which one of them comes first).

There may also be cases where a sorted list is not possible due to contradictory instructions (for example, if `5` claimed to come after `4` and `4` claimed to come after `5`). In that case the offending elements would need to be removed from the input, and the remaining elements would have to be sorted again. I don't want to throw an exception in the middle of sorting because I'd rather sort the items as much as possible and then later get information about which ones couldn't be included.

I briefly skimmed through [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), which seems to be similar to what I want, but from what I understand it only works when each element knows the elements that come before it, not both before and after.

So my question is, is there a sorting algorithm that can help me achieve what I need? And if not, is there a way to transform such an input list into a directed acyclic graph such that I can apply a topological sort algorithm?

Comment: What happens if you have a circular reference with two items both specifying the other should come before it?

Comment: It's easy enough to write a comparer for two items. I'd suggest one pass to find any pairs that cannot be sorted and then another pass to sort the remainder.

Comment: @DavidG in that case, those two items should be removed from the list and the sorting proceeds with the rest of them.

Comment: @user18387401 thanks for the reply. This was originally what I was doing, but it was a mess and also required multiple passes over the input list. I was wondering if there was an algorithm that could do it in O(n) time.